# Can Automapper map a dynamic object with fewer properties than the mapping source class?

Tags: c#, dynamic, automapper

I have a basic automapper mapping between Foo and Bar

```
        CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
            .ForMember(dest =>dest.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item1))
            .ForMember(dest =>dest.Property2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item2))
            .ForMember(dest =>dest.Property3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Item3))

        class Foo
        {
             string Property1 { get; set; }
             string Property2 { get; set; }
             string Property3 { get; set; }
        }

        class Bar
        {
             string Item1 { get; set; }
             string Item2 { get; set; }
             string Item3 { get; set; }
        }
```

I want to use the mapper above to map this object.

```
var toMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{Property1: "myproperty", Property2: null }");
var mapped = _mapper.Map<Foo, Bar>(toMap);
```

**My problem:** How can I tell the difference between:

- *mapped.Item2 = null:* because Property2 = null
- *mapped.Item3 = null:* because Property3 was not in the JSON

**My question:**

- Can automapper support this? (Maybe with help from C#)

The only thing I could find that might be a part of the answer is this https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: After you deserialized it to `Foo`, there is no way to tell, why some property holds a `null` value.
You could parse the json into `JsonNode` or `JsonDocument` and  check properties manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Automapper issue. This is a deserialization issue.

When you call `mapper.Map`, the `Foo` object is already built, and null values on the source will be mapped as is to the destination object.

Check out `ContainsKey` method on [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwXTm9)